# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un problema en una parte del código donde me tira el error **Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.**, Tengo agregada la propiedad key pero al tener un if dentro del map me arroja ese warning. Si borro el if y pruebo dejando uno de los componentes no se muestra el error pero si hago el if se muestra.

```
return(
       
            <div className="main">
                {video.map(vid => (
                    <>
                    { vid.video !== '' ? (  
                         <VideoPlayer id={vid.id} video={vid.video} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} key={vid.id}  />
                    ) : (
                        <ImgNoVideo id={vid.id} url={vid.url} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} key={vid.id} />
                    )}
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>
    );
```

Comment: Yo intentaría con retornar los componentes hijos. Lo que haría es lo siguiente: `return <VideoPlayer id={vid.id} video={vid.video} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} key={vid.id}  />`. Y, `return <ImgNoVideo id={vid.id} url={vid.url} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} key={vid.id} />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede usar la versión completa del componente `Fragment`, este componente acepta la propiedad `key` si se usa de esta forma.

Versión shorthand de `Fragment`:

```
<>Some JSX</>
```

Versión completa de `Fragment`:

```
<Fragment key={id}>Some JSX</Fragment>
```

Demo:

```js
const video = [
  {
    id:0,
    video:"video va",
    name:"name value 0",
    url:"url va",
    poster:"poster va"
  },
  {
    id:1,
    video:"video va 1",
    name:"name value 1",
    url:"url va 1",
    poster:"poster va 1"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    video:"video va 2",
    name:"name value 2",
    url:"url va 2",
    poster:"poster va 2"
  }
]

function App(){
  return (
    <div className="main">
    {video.map(vid => (
        <React.Fragment key={vid.id}>
        { vid.video !== '' ? (  
            <VideoPlayer id={vid.id} video={vid.video} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} />
        ) : (
            <ImgNoVideo id={vid.id} url={vid.url} name={vid.name} poster={vid.poster} />
        )}
        </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </div>
  )
}

function VideoPlayer(props){
  return (
    <p>{props.name}</p>
  )
}

function ImgNoVideo(props){
  return (
    <p>{props.name}</p>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.